# Original File and test_module file giving different answers for the same case

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, import

I'm a little new to coding and was working on a replit project but couldn't figure out why the test_modules file kept giving an `AssertionError` even though the code worked fine on the main file.

Original file budget_app.py (for this question only focusing on deposit function is enough):

```
class Category:

  def __init__(self, title):
    self.title = title

  ledger = []

  def deposit(self, amount=0, description=""):
    self.ledger.append({"amount": amount, "description": description})

  def withdraw(self, amount=0, description=""):
    if not self.check_funds(amount):
      return False
    amount = -1 * amount
    self.ledger.append({"amount": amount, "description": description})
    return True

  def get_balance(self):
    totalAmount = 0
    for i in self.ledger:
      totalAmount += i["amount"]
    return totalAmount

  def transfer(self, amount, cat):
    if not self.check_funds(amount):
      return False
    self.withdraw(amount, ("Transfer to " + cat.title))
    cat.deposit(amount, ("Transfer from " + self.title))
    return True

  def check_funds(self, amount):
    if amount > self.get_balance():
      return False
    return True
```

Test Module:

```
import unittest
import budget_app



class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    maxDiff = None
    def setUp(self):
        self.food = budget_app.Category("Food")
        self.entertainment = budget_app.Category("Entertainment")
        self.business = budget_app.Category("Business")

    def test_deposit(self):
        self.food.deposit(900, "deposit")
        actual = self.food.ledger[0]
        expected = {"amount": 900, "description": "deposit"}
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected `deposit` method to create a specific object in the ledger instance variable.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The error I am facing when I run this test_module.py file is

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_deposit (__main__.UnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fnafb\OneDrive\Desktop\programming\python programs\test_modules.py", line 17, in test_deposit
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected, 'Expected `deposit` method to create a specific object in the ledger instance variable.')
AssertionError: {'amount': 10, 'description': 'deposit'} != {'amount': 900, 'description': 'deposit'}
- {'amount': 10, 'description': 'deposit'}
?            ^

+ {'amount': 900, 'description': 'deposit'}
?            ^^
 : Expected `deposit` method to create a specific object in the ledger instance variable.

======================================================================
```

It is claiming that my deposit function returns `{'amount': 10, 'description': 'deposit'}` instead of `{'amount': 900, 'description': 'deposit'}`

however when I check this issue directly in the main file by adding the lines (I'm running budget.py file)

```
food = Category("Food")
food.deposit(900, "deposit")
actual = food.ledger[0]
print(actual)
```

The output is `{'amount': 900, 'description': 'deposit'}` which is the required output

I'm getting similar errors for multiple similar test cases. All of them work in the main file